# Show horizontal php table vertically with php query

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

please help i am getting so frustrated that i cant work this out. i have a php table like this. sorry im pretty new to this, i have tried a lot of queries and loop and it does not work.

[My php table looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhOnc.png)

[This is my expected output of the table using php queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04AIl.png)

i have tried using this code

```
$kunci = '';
$kriterium = '';

require('../connect.php');
$sqldatabase2 = "   SELECT *  FROM test_jawaban ";
$querysekolah2 = mysqli_query($connection, $sqldatabase2);

if (!$querysekolah2) {
    die ('SQL Error: ' . mysqli_error($connection));
}
while ($rowkas = mysqli_fetch_array($querysekolah2)) {
    $kriterium = '<td  class="fixed">' . $rowkas['namamurid'] . '</td>';
    $kunci .= '<td>' . $rowkas['kunci'] . '</td>';
    echo '<div class="container">
<table>
    <tr>
        ' . $kriterium . '
        <td>' . $kunci . '</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace this line

```
      $kunci .= '<td>'.$rowkas['kunci'].'</td>';echo'<div class="container">
```

to

```
     $kunci = '<td>'.$rowkas['kunci'].'</td>';echo'<div class="container">
```

Comment: That’s still going to produce invalid HTML, you can not have a `div` as a sibling of a `td` …